# Performing rotation and scale change cause object to disappear from render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am creating an anime-based render but having a hard time with what seems like a bug. I had set up a scene in my viewport a particular way but when I went to render it out, it seemed to disappear. When I saved, closed, and re-opened it, the rotation, location, and scale of the collection causing the problem seemed to change altogether. When I tried to correct its scale, position, and rotation, it disappeared once again.

*Ignore the pink missing textures, they are irrelevant to the problem

Image on opening file, Collection should be rotated as shown in red:
[image]

After doing appropriate Scale, Rotation and Location Changes (Looking fine in render view)
[image]

Final Render output not having the clouds and shooting star:
[image]

I have checked out all the common "things not appearing in render" problems though none seem to be the reason here.

Any solutions would be incredibly helpful!

Find source file here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3Y2P_sXSq35FCPvC6wNf3Jz_jNS1t8A/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had accidentally keyframed the collection, removing which solved the problem